# SQL Server select XML node by user define attribute value

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012, attributes, sqlxml

How to fetch the xml node by its attribute value which is user define

I want to replace 2 in query with `@pagenumber_`

```
Declare @pagenumber_ varchar(max);
Set @pagenumber_ = '2';

Select applicationdata.query('(/applicationdata/page[@number="2"])[1]')  
From Applications
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-extension-functions-sql-variable?view=sql-server-2016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Applications
(
    applicationdata XML
);

INSERT INTO #Applications (applicationdata)
VALUES ('<applicationdata><page number="1">page1</page><page number="2">page2</page></applicationdata>')


DECLARE @pagenumber_ VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @pagenumber_ = '2';

SELECT applicationdata.query('(/applicationdata/page[@number=sql:variable("@pagenumber_")])[1]')  
FROM #Applications

DROP TABLE #Applications
```